# How to put navbar brand to right side in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a complete right-aligned navbar in bootstrap but the problem is my brand is in the left side but I need it to go to right side. Although I can put other list items using `navbar-right` option to the right side.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand pull-right" href="#">CesaStack</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">بیاب</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>
```

Comment: He is using boostrap version 4 In the boostrap version 4, the class is pull-right.

Answer (score 35):

Move the brand above the navbar-header and give it the class navbar-right.

This puts your brand on right when in desktop views, and it goes left in mobile views, properly keeping the menu button as the rightmost element.

http://jsfiddle.net/KHtU4/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">CesaStack</a>
  <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>          
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <!-- snip -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Suppose I want brand on right side in both desktop and mobile view... Moreover navbar-header i want on left side in both views. please suggest ans

Comment: link appears to be broken

Comment: link should be fixed now

Answer (score 9):

The brand is on the left side, even though it has the class `.pull-right`, because it is contained in

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   ..
   <a class="navbar-brand pull-right" href="#">CesaStack</a>
</div>
```

if you place it outside, just after `.navbar-header`->`</div>`, then it will be aligned to the right as it should.

See your code in this fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9BfjX/**

Comment: This doesn't look right in mobile views. In the older bootstrap, you could put the brand on the right so that in desktop, it would go [menu items][brand], and in mobile, it would be [brand][menu button]. This method causes the brand to go to a new row underneath the menu button.

Comment: @friggle, you mean mobile with bootstrap 3.x?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I was trying to say when I typed my above comment. Using the method you've given, when the navbar collapses, the brand will be on another row below the navbar-toggle. Just look in your fiddle. Look at the fiddle in my answer to see the difference.

Answer (score 7):

What you need to use is **`navbar-right`** not pull-right

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          **LOGO OR HEADER NAME HERE**

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-right collapse">

          **OTHER MENU OR FORM HERE**

        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">right</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">right</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">right</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You should add at least a comment explaining your solution.

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux  add navbar-right class in ul tag move menu right side                            
add navbar-left class in ul tag move menu left side