# How to place right side fixed navigation bar in Twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add 4 navigation buttons at right side. On Clicking which I would be able to navigate to respective divs in the same page.(just like a single page design).

I am adding following lines of codes to create 4 navigation buttons at right side of the page.

```
    <div data-spy="affix" class="offset8 span1 well offset7 small">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <a class=".move-1" data-target=".home-1-image"> A </a>
            <a class=".move-1" data-target=".home-2-image"> B </a>
            <a class=".move-1" data-target=".home-3-image"> C </a>
            <a class=".move-1" data-target=".home-4-image"> D </a>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

But those lines of codes are not placing my 4 buttons at extreme right.  Check snapshot. 
[image]

Which bootstrap classes can be used to make it place at extreme right side and those should be fixed in position. (responsiveness should be well taken care of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to use navbar-right, as I found out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22652343/453673) and used in my code:

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use `.navbar-right` and also add `position: fixed; right: 0;`. 
that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div data-spy="affix" class="offset8 span1 well offset7 small  nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <a class=".move-1" data-target=".home-1-image"> A </a>
            <a class=".move-1" data-target=".home-2-image"> B </a>
            <a class=".move-1" data-target=".home-3-image"> C </a>
            <a class=".move-1" data-target=".home-4-image"> D </a>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav {

    position: fixed;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 0px;

   }
```